# How can I delete a charcter from string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, character-encoding

How can I delete a character from string in PHP ?

$s = "waseem";

Are there a function like delChar($s , 2); ?
which 2 is the index of the Character , I search but I didn't find anything .
any ideas ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[substr_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) is what you want.

```
$s = substr_replace($s, '', 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s[2] = '';
```